# ReactiveMongo BSONHandler for Map

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I have following class, and want to use `reactivemongo.bson.Macros.handler` to get the reader and writer automatically.

```
case class Data(a: String, b: Map[String, String])
object Data {
  implicit val dataHandler = reactivemongo.bson.Macros.handler[Data]
}
```

But it fails to compile, saying `Implicit Map[String,String] for 'value vs' not found`

How to make this work? I'm using `reactivemongo_2.10 0.11.10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dbalduini/c772e54c9a9ea4e17152), I find a solution as:

```
case class Data(date: String, base: String, vs: Map[String, String])

object Data {
  implicit object BSONMapHandler extends BSONHandler[BSONDocument, Map[String, String]] {
    override def read(bson: BSONDocument): Map[String, String] = {
      bson.elements.map {
        case (key, value) => key -> value.asInstanceOf[BSONString].value
      }.toMap
    }

    override def write(t: Map[String, String]): BSONDocument = {
      val stream: Stream[Try[(String, BSONString)]] = t.map {
        case (key, value) => Try((key, BSONString(value)))
      }.toStream
      BSONDocument(stream)
    }
  }
  implicit val dataHandler = reactivemongo.bson.Macros.handler[Data]
}
```

Don't know why reactivemongo not support it by default.

Comment: Supporting a dictionary, instead of having typed case classed, doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @cchantep when the case class contains a field of type `Map`, the user has to implement something to get things work, it seems not very convenient.

Comment: @cchantep You are stating, not reasoning. Please tell us _why_ it doesn't seem very useful to you?